# Using ui.router in AngularJS, Grunt webserver seems to not monitoring changes to views?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, angular-ui-router

I am pretty new to AngularJS. Have created a few example applications. I am using Yeoman to scaffold the apps and then add controllers, directives and views.

I switched to use **ui.router** but noticed that Grunt webserver does not seem to monitor changes in the views anymore. If I change a view and save the change the **browser does not auto-refresh** like it used to do.

Is this a known problem or am I just doing something wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gruntfile.js, you should ensure that the templates are monitored.

Probably you have something similar under the watcher's config section:

```
files: [
  '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
  '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
  '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
]
```

And probably your templates are not covered by your config. You can add them easily for example by adding the next entry to this js array:

```
'path/to/you/templates/**/*.html'
```

Comment: Embarrassing that I did not see that! Thanks